different Program Id on devnet than in lib declare_id!
While deploying app to Devnet it returned a different program Id than declared in the macro
declare_id!.
Then when I try to do transaction on the app, I have an error 'Error Code: DeclaredProgramIdMismatch. Error Number: 4100. Error Message: The declared'
In that case should I deploy program to the same id that was declared in the declare_id ?
like: anchor deploy --provider.cluster devnet  --program-id <PROGRAM_ID>
when I run anchor keys list I have response with the ID deployed to devnet and that create that error on the frontend

Also make sure you're using the updated IDL

Your generated program I'd when deploying should match the one in the declare_id macro
You can get this after building your program using the anchor CLI command
anchor keys list

